# "global" dimension constraints for vehicle routing

Tags: or-tools

As I understand it, there are two types of dimension variables in or-tools: "cumulative" quantities specific to a single node, and "transit" quantities dependent on the graph edge (connection between 2 nodes) and these are merely summed to create a total route cost.

I am trying to create route cost that depends globally on all the nodes, however: values like the convex hull or the total volume encompassed.  In general, I need the cost function callback to be a function of all the nodes in the current route candidate, rather than just the current node or edge.  Is there a way the callback can access the entire route like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is explicitly forbidden by the solver